# Share interval, built-in Delphi function?

Tags: delphi

I have to find the shared interval of `INTERVALL-1 = [x1.....y1]`
and `INTERVALL-2 := [x2 .....y2]`

All are simple real-value defined intervals. Are there any built-in functions in the Delphi syntax or some free stuff where I can get the shared range with no special coding myself ?

What I want to avoid :

```
 procedure Findintervall ( ...........)
 begin
 if x1 < x2 then  
   if ....
      if .... 
         if 

 end;
```

Guess this could be the code, but it is hard to read 5 months later.

Comment: If you make use of the `Min()` and `Max()` functions you should be able to get rid of most of the `if`s and arrive at fairly readable code.

Comment: If your interval can reasonably be based on a **set** type, you could use set operations to find the intersection.

Comment: @CraigYoung A set is not the right way to store an interval. You really do need to store just the two end points, and not every value in between.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Agreed, which is why I posted merely as a comment. I did state the condition if it can be _reasonably_ based on a set. I certainly don't know the particulars of OPs intervals. I'm just bringing attention to a feature that may not have been considered.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan As an example if OP wishes to process all values in the intersection of two `Byte` intervals, the following is quite elegant: `for LIntersect in [LStart1..LEnd1] * [LStart2..LEnd2] do`.

Comment: @CraigYoung It might well be elegant. But then how do you find the min or max. And how do you stop the user from making a value that has missing values.

Comment: @Craig What you could do is use operator overloading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing built in but it's not very difficult to write the function. You can write it with explicit `if` statements. Or you can use `Min` and `Max` from the `Math` unit. Like this:

```
type
  TInterval = record
  public
    Left: Double;
    Right: Double;
  public
    class function New(const Left, Right: Double): TInterval; static;
    class function Intersection(const A, B: TInterval): TInterval; static;
  end;

const
  NullInterval: TInterval = (Left: NaN; Right: NaN);

class function TInterval.New(const Left, Right: Double): TInterval;
begin
  Result.Left := Left;
  Result.Right := Right;
end;

class function TInterval.Intersection(const A, B: TInterval): TInterval;
begin
  Assert(A.Left<=A.Right);
  Assert(B.Left<=B.Right);
  Result.Left := Max(A.Left, B.Left);
  Result.Right := Min(A.Right, B.Right);
  if Result.Left > Result.Right then
    Result := NullInterval;
end;
```

Comment: what is the content of the function :   class function New(const Left, Right: Double): TInterval; static;

Comment: @user1769184 It's just a simple helper. Now added

Comment: after new the vales of a Tinterval instance is always 0, should the new code  goe like this    self.left := left ?  .....

Comment: No. The code is fine. You are calling it wrong. I think. You didn't show how you call it. Look again at the declaration. It's a function that returns a `TInterval`. Don't call it as an instance method like I suspect you are. Do it like this: `Interval := TInterval.New(left, right);`

Comment: OK, I did it the wrong way aInterval.new (left, right) ; Thanks for the advise

Comment: Mutating instance methods on records are very dangerous. You should avoid them at all costs. Instead have functions that return new values. The big difference is that records are value types and classes are reference types. For values, don't have mutating methods. FWIW, the FireMonkey designers screwed this up monumentally and as a result that platform commits this terrible sin over and over again.